# Page number problem while pagination

Tags: visualforce, pagination

I'm trying out Pagination and I have a weird problem :

Whenever the total number of my input in multiple's of 10's (eg, 10, 30, 100 etc, and its 40 in current problem), the pagination will give me an **EXTRA** page.

Say I want to show 10 records/results per "pagination page", it will display the first 40 perfectly. 1-10 (page 1 of 4), 11-20 (page 1 of 4), 21-30 (page 1 of 4), 31-40 (page 1 of 4).

**It will ALSO display an empty page (page 5 of 4).**

[VF page](http://codepad.org/iVGuqpY6)

[Controller](http://codepad.org/gr5B8OJ3)

I am unable to find the cause of this "problem".

Any help in pinning down the cause would be HIGHLY appreciated.

Comment: In the one case you're doing `integer i=1;<41;i++`. In another place you're starting with `counter = 0` and adjusting for it by adding 1 to your code elsewhere. Be consistent. I think this is the source of your issue. Use `i=0;<40;i++` and account for the same adjustments everywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is in your end button reference.

```
counter = total_size - math.mod(total_size, list_size);
```

which is ok for non multiples of 10.
for multiples of 10 this should be:

```
counter = total_size - list_size;
```

Otherwise your next page will start from a counter of (in this example) 40 and create an empty page.
try the following:

```
if(math.mod(total_size, list_size) == 0){
   counter = total_size - list_size;
}
else{
   counter = total_size - math.mod(total_size, list_size);
}
```

Comment: Can you add a little more explanation for why the one approach is wrong and your recommendation is correct? Or how you can make them both fit together if that's necessary?

Comment: Just PERFECT. Thank you, I understand now what was wrong, passing the original `counter` the old way was artificially "expanding" the page numbers. I love answers like yours, everything just "clicks" into place leading to an "AHA!" moment!